# Sublime Text 2 Referencing external css

Tags: css, intellisense, sublimetext2

I would like to have 'IntelliSense' from class names when using Sublime Text2.

The CSS file is in an include file which is passed in a run-time.

However, while developing, I would like to have my styles available when add class="xxx".

Is there a setting that I can add to point the current page or project to always look/referencing my css files?

Comment: I really need to know this too, I found this video about cTags which looks like it might do that for php, but I don't know if it would work for css. (I haven't had time to watch the video all the way through yet, but if you think it might be useful then give it a watch): https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=5j8H73iPd7k#!